# Webgl streetview with ie - virtual Tour Google

Tags: javascript, webgl, google-street-view, virtual-tour

I'm trying to add, in a Google Street View include in a website, , à map with a point moving during the visit.

See this exemple : http://www.culturemediatic.fr/demos/TestAPIVVP/point_qui_suit_la_visite.html

It wortks with Chrome and firefox, but not with ie and Smartphones.

I think the cause is with Webgl.

Help ?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually unrelated to WebGL. In pov_changed(), you are setting the WebKit, Mozilla, and Opera prefixed variations of the “transform” property, but you are not setting the Microsoft-prefixed (msTransform) or unprefixed (transform) variants of the property. IE supports both the Microsoft-prefixed and the unprefixed variants. Adding either should fix your issue.

Disclosure: I am on a member of Microsoft’s Internet Explorer team.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Like that ? floorplan.style.ms-transform = "perspective(600px) rotateX(50deg) rotateZ("+heading+"deg)";
    floorplan.style.webkitTransform = "perspective(600px) rotateX(50deg) rotateZ("+heading+"deg)";
    floorplan.style.mozTransform = "perspective(600px) rotateX(50deg) rotateZ("+heading+"deg)";
    floorplan.style.oTransform = "perspective(600px) rotateX(50deg) rotateZ("+heading+"deg)"; cf http://www.culturemediatic.fr/demos/TestAPIVVP/point_qui_suit_la_visite_pegman.html

Comment: Close, but not quite. The ms-prefixed CSS property is “-ms-transform”, but to set it via JavaScript you would use “msTransform”. I also recommend setting the unprefixed version: “transform”.

Answer (score 0):

Problem issued with http://www.culturemediatic.fr/demos/TestAPIVVP/point_qui_suit_la_visite_pegman.html

With Mobile detect for html5/html4